# Connecting keys & values to user input

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a random glossary exam in python, where the user can choose how many words they wish to translate. If the users translation is true, python prints "correct", if false "wrong answer, the correct answer is XX". I have a given dictionary d, my question is; How do I connect the keys & values (in d) to the users input?

```
import random

d = {"one" : "uno", "two" : "dos", "three" : "tres", "four" : "cuatro", "five" : "cinco"}

word = random.choice(list(d.keys()))

print("Translate", word,":")
answ = input()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you practically wrote the code yourself:

```
translation = d[word]

if answ == translation:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong answer, the correct answer is {}".format(translation))
```

Comment: One more, use `answ.lower()` to ensure  you handle capital/small letter issues. Otherwise **uno** and **Uno** will not match

Answer (score 1):

Just compare `answ` to `d[word]` with `==`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
print "Correct!" if answ == d[word] else "Wrong answer, the correct answer is {}".format(d[word]))"
```

And you will need to add a while loop to iterate the number of times as many words the user has selected (and ask the user the same) at the beginning.